# Putting Labels in between the fields in elementor form

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form, elementor

I am trying to create an Elementor form. The requirement is to put in between labels. I am not getting the option of just putting the label without the fields. Below are the screenshots

[image: This is how the form is looking. But the label " A password will be sent to your email address." should just come as label.]

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elmentor form builder, in type you choose "HTML" and in the HTML section you write something like this:

```
<p>A password will be sent to you email address</p>
```